# Cerberus oneof two keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, cerberus

I have a set of schemas I'm using to validate one of my input routes:

```
# schemas is just a dict of validator schemas
REGISTRATION_VALIDATOR = {
    'email_address': schemas['email_address'],
    'user_level': schemas['user_level'],
    'first_name': schemas['first_name'],
    'last_name': schemas['last_name'],
    'mobile_number': schemas['mobile_number'],
    'auth_method': schemas['auth_method']
}
```

but I need to define that either `email_address` or `mobile_number` is required but not both. How to require only one of those two keys?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`excludes`](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#excludes) rule that you can set for both fields, pointing with the constraint to the other.